# Netbeans can't add remote host running on Virtualbox

Tags: netbeans, ssh, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu Server 15 on VirtualBox 5.0.10 and set up ssh access to the guest using NAT/port forwarding (host:3022->guest:22). The host is Windows 7 64bit.

I can successfully access the Ubuntu server via putty or other ssh client from an external computer (not the host). But NetBeans 8.0.2 can't complete adding the remote host. It just freezes on "Connecting ip_addr:3022..." stage (authentication type is 'Password')

What can be the reason? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the reason is that `com-jcraft-jsch.jar` distributed with NetBeans 8.0.2 doesn't work with OpenSSH 6.9 distributed with Ubuntu 15. There is a [workaround for this](https://superuser.com/questions/972996/create-a-sftp-connection-in-netbeans), but unfortunately it doesn't work with OpenSSH 6.9.

I was able to resolve the issue after I downloaded and built OpenSSH-5.4 (requires `zlib-dev`, `libssl-dev` and some other packages). To use existant ssh config files you need to configure OpenSSH properly before build:

```
./configure --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh
make
sudo make install
```

Please note that `make install` will install binaries in `/usr/local/bin`, configuration files in `/usr/local/etc`, the server in `/usr/local/sbin`, etc. To specify a different installation prefix, use the `--prefix` option to configure.

You may need to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file (at least to point to `sftp-server`) and you may want to modify `/etc/init.d/ssh`, but anyway, OpenSSH-5.4 does work with NetBeans 8.0.2.

UPD: NetBeans 8.0.2 also works correctly with OpenSSH 6.6.1